# Part-time AD server

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I'm trying to understand how current Win 7/8 machines behave when they lose access to their domain controller and if it's possible to have machines be part of a domain if domain exists only part time (e.g. due to bad wan link or just no access to the server).

As an independent admin I have small shops that cannot afford a proper windows domain solution but I could benefit from the single sign on Admin access, and maybe a few more perks, of having them be part of a domain.  If I'm hosting a DC at my office, let's assume that it may or may not be available, perhaps even for long periods of time - what happens to the machines in the office that are without their DC? (in my mind this is quite like a laptop that could be out of office for weeks at a time, isn't it?)

Can this be set up in such a way as that the offices would continue to function regardles of their ability to reach the DC but that when the DC was reachable, they would talk, maybe push policies and (re)confirm some user credentials/login access?

So for example office A with 4 computers can continue to talk to their 2 onsite printers, their samba nas, the Internet, and possibly each other, office B has similar functions within itself, and when the vpn to my office comes online late at night, everyone will talk to the DC and get what they need.
Possible?

Comment: I think you're going to find a lot of dissatisfaction on the part of your users, and in your own experience supporting them. Ultimately if there's no domain for the users to authenticate to, you're relying on cached passwords on the machines, and that plus coordinating your AD server being available when the users need to change their password or (and you know they will) forget their passwords. This sounds like it will be a lot of hassle. Maybe look into workgroups, or a little local DC that maybe replicates to your central AD server.

Comment: Thanks Kate.  The point is these shops are so small that those objections are the least problematic and in my control.  They won't change passwords unless I tell or force them too.  They won't change passwords so they're not gonna forget them.  They don't really use machines other than their own so cached logins will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a supported configuration as far as I know, for any number of reasons.

The cached credentials mechanism, for example, which allows users to log in to a domain account without communication with the DC, is designed to provide local authorization and is likely to fail eventually (when the relevant Kerberos tokens expire, if I recall) when trying to authorize with remote services like network printers.

DCs also provide DNS, which is preferentially used to locate network resources (NBNS/WINS is a legacy protocol in that case).

For admin signon, you should consider that you will often need the local administrator password anyway, if their trust channel to the domain desyncs (a common problem requiring rejoining the computer to the domain) or if you haven't used the domain admin login on that computer before (credentials are only cached for local signon after a signon).

If all you want to do is remote management, consider something else that is amenable to this approach.  There is a lot of deployment and configuration management software out there.

Comment: Thanks.  I have looked through some of the offerings but one of the primary things I want is a single sign on for me as an admin on all the machines and NAS. I need this for scanning and other softwares I use (like spiceworks for example) Most of the deployment/management stuff doesn't address that afaik.

Comment: No, the typical approach is to set the local admin password by policy, for various reasons such as the need for local access when centralized logins do not work.

Comment: So using a deployment tool, push out a policy creating the admin user and setting it's password?

Comment: Exactly.  Almost everything I've encountered supports that.

Comment: Is a little far from the stated topic (and I'll start another if approp.) but any suggestions for a free but good deploy tool?  Many roads point to PDQ but is a bit expensive for me at this juncture.

Comment: I'm not really in the habit of making these kinds of endorsements, for various reasons, but good luck in your search.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using something like Logmein Himachi to maintain a constant remote connection to a centralized server. It's easy to setup and maintain as well as inexpensive. Big issue with no server for AD workstations is you'll need to start unplugging the patch cable to login.

Comment: They can use cached credentials even with a network connection.